# How do I use @GetMapping properly (SpringBoot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Basically, I'm using spring boot and thymeleaf to create a web site for a restaurant catering (just an exercise for a class) where chefs offer buffets and where each buffet is made up of different dishes with different ingredients (sorry for my english).

My question is: should I use `@GetMapping("/chef/{id}/buffets")` to indicate the buffets made by a chef?

Or should I just use `("/buffet")`? Because for the ingredient's controller I will end up using `("/chef/{id}/buffet/{id}/plate{id}/ingredients")` and it looks weird, but I dont think I can do it any other ways.

Also, how do I write it in thymeleaf to link chef and his own buffets etc.?
Thank you for your help.

UPDATE: ok but now i'm stuck. let's say I use this code to get a chef in particular:

```
    @GetMapping("/chef/{id}")
    public String getChef(@PathVariable("id")Long id, Model model) {

        Chef chef = cs.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("chef",chef);
        return "chef.html";
    }
```

How would the function to get all the buffets made by that chef be?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about how to use @GetMapping() in Spring but to understand REST URI API.

For your type of problem, you will need to expose a URI like you said above :

```
"/chef/{chef_id}/buffet/{buffet_id}/plate/{plate_id}/ingredients"
```

The reason being, as you mentionned above, is each chef as many buffets and each buffet has many plates and each plate has many ingredients.

[chef] 1---* [buffet] 1---* [plate] 1---* [ingredients]

Exposing a URI such as `/buffet` will have to list all the buffets for ALL the chefs in your database

Here's a link to a good article about good practices for REST API
https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/

Comment: I edited my comment - added more explanation

Comment: I've updated my question, if you can help me let me know